# Recover removed mirror drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, filesystems, data-recovery, mirroring

I had a pair of hard drives set up in a mirror.

I removed one of the mirrored drives as I could not restore the mirror, expecting to be able to access the files on the drive. However the drive is now showing as unallocated and I can't access it without formatting it which doesn't seem like a good idea.

The other drive shows up as 'dynamic' and I haven't touched it.

Is there any way to access my files and recover my data from either drive?

Both drives are 2.5" internal HDs. Happy to provide more details but I don't know where to start with this. Help!

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser! As a starter for more information to provide, can yu tell us what kind of mirror it is? You don't mention RAID 1, which is the standard for mirrored HDDs. Another good idea would be a screenshot of the Disk Manager showing both disks and their paritions (unless it is confidential). Thanks!

Comment: @NathanShiraini I believe I mirrored it using the Windows Disk manager so just a software mirror? Apologies for knowing nothing here.

Comment: What controller card are you using, or how is mirroring set up ?  (You might also want to confirm or correct my supposition that mirroring = RAID1)

Comment: If it were me (and I'm a Linux, not Windows person), I'd be inclined to make a bit copy of the disk to another disk, then use testdisk on the second copy to see if it can find and correct partition table etc.

Comment: @davidgo - That is a Windows person's solution to this problem also.